# Maintaining type when binding to dynamic object - WPF / C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Say I have a class like so...

```
public class Field
{
    public Field(string fieldname, object fieldValue = null)
    {
        FieldName = fieldname;
        FieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public object FieldValue { get; set; }

}
```

And I am then binding to the class as such...

```
<Label Width="Auto" Content="{Binding FieldlName}"></Label>
<TextBox Width="Auto" Text="{Binding FieldValue, FallbackValue='error', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

I am having a problem where if **FieldValue** is set as an integer in code behind, but the user types a different integer in the text box, the type then changes to a string.

However, what i expect is for the values to maintain their type.

I realize that the problem is that the `Text` property is string and that it tries to make a conversion.

Therefor what I am looking for is a remedy to maintain the implicit type, some sort of validation, some sort of converter, something on the getter... that is what I am not entirely sure of doing?

Comment: Without knowing more about why `FieldValue` would have to be dynamic, I'd probably put some type conversion logic in its setter. `Field` could also implement `IDataErrorInfo` so any conversion failures could set an appropriate error.

Comment: To clarify, i was playing around with the differences between **object** type and **dynamic** type at the time when I wrote the question initially I was using **object** to define the value as that the value can be of string, int, double, datatime, bool, etc.. 
The important thing to me is that it can maintain its type.

Comment: It is keeping it's type. The Text property of a TextBox is a string.

Comment: @Kevin I get that the cause is that `TextBox.Text` sets `FieldValue` to a string when the property is changed. However If I were to declare `FieldValue` as a int, it will maintain the int type.
I'm trying to solve how to maintain an int type when the property is declared as an object and implemented during run time as an int.
Does that make more sense?

Comment: When you enter 1 into a TextBox you are not entering the number 1, you are entering the string"1" into the TextBox. When you access that string you've entered via the Text property, you get back the string. It has nothing to do with how you declare the field in your object. Since you've declared it as dynamic, it will take on the type of what you put in it e.g. string. If you want to enter a number into the string of a TextBox and get it out as a number, you'll have to detect that the string contains a number and parse it into the number type you want it to be.

Comment: @Kevin I understand that and that I am asking for advise on what mechanism would be most appropriate to solve my problem of maintaining the type.

Comment: Whats also interesting is that if the `FieldValue` type is declared as int, then 1) it will maintain the type by (what i am assuming is) automatically casting the value 2) when a non integer string is entered it displays a validation error automatically.

Comment: Using `dynamic` causes late binding (any field access or method call on a `dynamic` object is resolved at run-time). As far as I know this was added to make interop with COM and other languages easier. Just stick to `object` unless you need that behavior. Either way, the binding system won't convert the incoming string because it's looking at the type of the *property*, not at the type of the *current value* of that property.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Yeah, I thought that looking for some mechanism to allow a type to resolve at run time to be maybe a solution and dynamic seemed to have those qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the text box is always a string, there is no way to change that (unless you use a different component). However, the WPF binding engine does attempt to convert types when updating the bound properties.

When your view model’s property is of type `string` then the target type matches the type of the source (the text field’s text property), so everything is just updated.

So when your view model’s property is of type `int`, then whatever you enter into the text box will be attempted to be converted into an int. If that works, that’s fine; if it doesn’t the view model property is not updated and a binding exception is instead thrown.

Now when your view model’s property is of type `object`, then when WPF attempts to store the *string* value into the view model’s property, then that just works. Regardless of its previous value (whether it was an int, or any other object). Since `string` is a subtype of `object`, the engine can just assign the string to the `object` property, so no type conversion happens.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify what i am actually asking for which it seems was not as obvious as I had first intended.

Comment: @TonyDasilva You will need to change the type on the view model to get some conversion. Or make it a string property and then in its setter, make the conversion yourself and store it in another property.